# Animated gif won't work properly in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, responsive-design, animated-gif, parallax

There seems to be a problem with getting a gif to work in Chrome. It works fine in FireFox and in Opera, but in Chrome it only seems to work when I keep scrolling around a bit. It might be useful to know I am building a responsive parallax website with a gif in it. I cannot find any information on this, only that Chrome sometimes will not play the gif at all.

Comment: I use Chrome and animated GIFs work fine for me. Are you able to post a sample GIF which is broken for you?

Comment: I can't post the website yet, but I wonder if there is a problem if the website is responsive or uses parallax scrolling. The gif is set as a background as 100%

Comment: Here is the gif: http://miet.be/images/gifke.gif

Comment: do you have any issues if you load that gif by itself in chrome (i.e. by clicking on the link you gave)? It displays fine for me.

Comment: No problem there, only on the website.

Comment: Okay, the problem was the gif was set as a background. Finally.Thank you for replying anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the gif was set as a background on 100%. When put it as an image inside the html, it worked again. This does not explain why, but it does provide a work around.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you still need a fix for this but this is what I had to do when the GIF was a background image.  Chrome caches the GIF so it only plays once. You have to 'force' the animation to play again with some jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myContainer").css("background-image", "url(/images/myAnimation.gif?"+ Math.random() + ")" );
});
</script>
```

Pretty much you add a random number at the end of the GIF url to force the browser to replay the animation because it thinks it is a new instance of the image. 
I would still put the GIF in the CSS on your element background just in case of JS issues on browsers.

Kind of hacky but it works.

Comment: thank you, I don't need it anymore, but maybe next time!